# How to pass options to this function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How to pass options to the search function as described in the API section of [nlcst-search](https://github.com/syntax-tree/nlcst-search).

```
search(node, patterns, handler[, allowApostrophes|options])
```

I want to pass `allowDashes` option to it. The code I currently have is:

```
search(node, patterns, handler);
function handler(){
//my code
}
```

I tried `search(node, patterns, handler, allowDashes)` but it fails. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/syntax-tree/nlcst-search#api),

> options (Object) — Configuration: allowApostrophes (boolean, default:
>   false) — Configuration for nlcst-normalize);
>     allowDashes(boolean, default: false) — Configuration for nlcst-normalize);   allowLiterals(boolean, default: false) — Include literal phrases

`options` is an object with `allowDashes` as boolean.

Try:

```
search(node, patterns, handler, {allowDashes:true})
```